# Google Pay integration with Moneris Gateway using google-pay/react-button

Tags: reactjs, google-pay

I need to send payment detail to moneris for process payment. I am using google-pay/react-button. In Moneris documentation i need to load a function in index.html and use it in googlePay.js file but getting error "MonerisGooglePay is not defined" from googlePay.js file. Here is the link i am following
https://developer.moneris.com/en/Documentation/NA/E-Commerce%20Solutions/Google%20Pay/On%20The%20Web

Index.html:

```
<script async src="https://esqa.moneris.com/googlepay/googlepay-api.js"
onload="MonerisGooglePay.onReady()"></script>
```

googlePay.js:

```
paymentData["orderId"] = "Unique Order ID";
paymentData["amount"] = "Same as GoogleTransactionInfo()[`Total Price´]";
MonerisGooglePay.purchase(paymentData, function(response)
{
if ( response && response.receipt && response.receipt.ResponseCode &&
!isNaN(response.receipt.ResponseCode) )
{
if ( parseInt(response.receipt.ResponseCode) < 50 )
{
alert("Looks like the transaction is approved.");
}
else
{
alert("Looks like the transaction is declined.");
}
}
else
{
throw ("Error processing receipt.");
}
});
```

Comment: I suggest reaching out to the Moneris team about this.

Comment: They don't know react and they send me complete code in html that works fine. I need to load a function from script tag but it shows error MonerisGooglePay is not defined but that library i am loading contains this function and works fine when using in html file

Comment: Are you able create a sample app demonstrating your issue? e.g. with [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/react). There isn't enough information for me to go on. One thing to try is `<script async src="https://esqa.moneris.com/googlepay/googlepay-api.js"
onload="myFunction()"></script>` and add the following to your page `<script>function myFunction() { MonerisGooglePay.onReady(); }</script>`.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out

Comment: Might be a good idea to add the solution as an answer for anyone else who may have a similar problem.